# automatically share facebook posts on website

Tags: facebook, post

When I write a post on facebook, I need it to be published also in my website
Is there any automatic method? I found this but I can't figure out how to do it automatically

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts

Comment: start reading: https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved with Facebook fb-like-box